# Anaconda not installing at Windows 10: failed to extract packages

Tags: windows, anaconda, extract, failed-installation

After unistalling Anaconda installation which was not working properly, I tried to freshly install newest version from https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/windows/ , however, I always get "Failed to extract packages" error during installation. After showing details I can see that error happens when extracting  `_anaconda_depends-2023.09-py311` file (see below).

[image]

I tried to install to a different folder, install as an admin and installing miniconda instead and remove all python and anaconda files. If I ignore the error, it fails to link packages later on. Thx!

Comment: We are having this same issue? Any answers?

Comment: I found an older version here: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/
None of the 2023 version worked for me. 


I was able to install this: Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64.exe
It is python3.9 FYI.